# Joining 4 tables is leaving out a lot of rows, can't figure out why

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I'm using the Chinook database to practice SQLite and then adding some more search parameters to increase the rigor.

I'm trying to provide a query that includes the track name and customer name with each invoice line item and amount of each track.

There are 2240 invoice line items in the invoice line item table, and 412 invoices in the invoice table yet the code below only shows me 59 results which is the total number of customers.

What did I leave out that is preventing the query from showing all 2240 rows?

```
SELECT i.InvoiceLineId as 'Invoice Line ID', t.Name as 'Name of track purchased', i.UnitPrice as '$ Amount for Track', c.FirstName || ' ' || c.LastName as 'Customer Name'
FROM Track as t
JOIN InvoiceLine as i
    ON t.TrackId = i.InvoiceLineId
JOIN Invoice as i_n
    ON i.InvoiceLineId = i_n.InvoiceId
JOIN Customer as c
    ON i_n.InvoiceId = c.CustomerId;
```

Comment: This join predicate looks a bit suspect to me - `ON i_n.InvoiceId = c.CustomerId;`, Is there a `CustomerID` column in the `Invoice` table, if so, then you should probably be joining on that rather than `InvoiceID`

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: You probably want tests like `il.tid=t.tid`, `il.iid=i.iid` & `i.cid=c.cid`. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the table where you want to keep everything and then use `left join`:

```
FROM Invoice i_n LEFT JOIN
     InvoiceLine i
     ON i.InvoiceLineId = i_n.InvoiceId LEFT JOIN
     Track as t
     ON t.TrackId = i.InvoiceLineId LEFT JOIN 
     Customer as c
      ON i_n.InvoiceId = c.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, the default behavior for `JOIN` is an inner join.  As mentioned already, using a left join from the 2240 line item table should keep all the records.  Alternatively, if all the customers and tracking ids are associated with invoices, you can also replace `JOIN` with `FULL JOIN`.

```
SELECT i.InvoiceLineId as 'Invoice Line ID', t.Name as 'Name of track purchased', i.UnitPrice as '$ Amount for Track', c.FirstName || ' ' || c.LastName as 'Customer Name'
FROM Track as t
FULL JOIN InvoiceLine as i
    ON t.TrackId = i.InvoiceLineId
FULL JOIN Invoice as i_n
    ON i.InvoiceLineId = i_n.InvoiceId
FULL JOIN Customer as c
    ON i_n.InvoiceId = c.CustomerId;
```

Comment: SQLite does not support FULL join.